# Orientação a objetos no R: S3, S4 e Reference Class

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, r, paradigma-de-programação

O R possui, entre outras, três principais formas de orientação a objetos:

- S3;
- S4; e,
- Reference Classes.

Quais as principais diferenças entre os três métodos?

E como implementá-los (de preferência fornecer um exemplo mínimo e simples com código implementando cada um)?

Comment: Some readings like OO field guide from [Hadley advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html) may help to clarify.

Comment: @PauloCardoso, in Portuguese please :)

Comment: Parece-me muito ampla a pergunta pro SO, não? Talvez uma community wiki?

Answer (score 8):

A ideia do S3 e S4 no R e usar funções genéricas (que servem para diferentes objetos como parâmetro), mas garantir, apesar disso, que essa função vai se comportar de acordo com o tipo (=classe) do objeto que você esta mandando como parâmetro.

Por exemplo, se você chama a função `summary` e passa como parâmetro uma função linear usando `lm`, ela vai retornar os coeficientes etc. Se você chama essa função com um data.frame, ela vai retornar um sumario das colunas. Para diferentes inputs, essa(s) função(ões) tem métodos diferentes.

No paradigm S3, você cria a função genérica como (ex: `summary`) - veja código abaixo também

```
summary<- function (arg1, arg2,…)
    UseMethod("summary")
```

Em geral, a função `UseMethod` vai pegar o primeiro argumento que você mandou para a função genérica (`summary`, no caso), olhar o que esta definido como sua classe, e despachar de acordo. A função `UseMethod()` faz isso, procura por uma função de nome `summary.nomeDaSuaClasse`, e a executa com os parâmetros que você mandou.

Vantagens: acho que já ficou obvio
Desvantagens: não tem controle de absurdos. Você pode criar qualquer objeto e chamar de qualquer classe (veja código de exemplo). Você tem que confiar no programador. Segunda desvantagem, S3 só olha a classe de um parâmetro para fazer o despacho. Creio que haja mais desvantagens, mas me lembro dessas duas agora.

A classe S4 resolve esses problemas. Mas vou parar por aqui. E um pouco mais complicado e acho que a resposta ficaria muito longa. Vou resumir da seguinte forma: você usa uma função(`setGeneric()`) para criar sua função genérica. Depois você usa `setMethod()` para criar os métodos correspondentes, e depois varias outras funções para definir como essa função genérica e seus métodos vão operar.

Se estiver seguro e sua aplicação for relativamente simples, não vejo problema nenhum em usar S3.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

```
# criando um objeto (vetor com uma string)
meuObjeto <- "string"

# Veja a estrutura do seu objeto:
str(meuObjeto)

#Agora adicione mais strutura: uma classe
class(meuObjeto) <- 'minhaClasse'

# Veja a estrutura do seu objeto:
str(meuObjeto)

# Exemplos de objetos S3 (summary)
exClass_glm       <- glm(c(20:1) ~ c(1:20) )
exClass_dataframe <- data.frame(1:20)
str(exClass_glm) # a lot of structure
class(exClass_glm) # ... and two classes

# veja a diferenca: nao ha methodo para a clsse "minhaClasse", porque nao definimos nada
summary(exClass_glm)
summary(exClass_dataframe)
summary(meuObjeto)

# mas se voce define um metodo para sua classe....
summary.minhaClasse <- function (x,y,...) {
print('Hey, olha so !!')
paste('minha string e:',meuObjeto)
}
summary(meuObjeto)

# mas S3 e coracao de mae e aceita qualquer coisa, o que pode gerar erro em algum momento do codigo
x <- 3
summary(x)
class(x) <- 'glm'
summary(x)
```

Answer (score 6):

Sugiro a leitura de alguns textos muito elucidativos sobre a questão que foi colocada:

### Documentos

- Um [Tutorial](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~statcur/WorkshopBC/Presentations/AdvancedProgramming/OOP2x2.pdf) da U. Berkeley;
- Conteúdos produzidos por Hadley W. [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html);

### Manuais do projeto CRAN

- Sobre a própria [linguagem R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf);
- Introdução ao modelo de objeto [S4](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Genolini-S4tutorialV0-5en.pdf)

### Questões semelhantes no SE e SO

- Sobre o modelo S4[aqui](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4575/tutorials-on-object-oriented-programming-in-r)
- Sobre o modelo S3 [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583265/what-does-s3-methods-mean-in-r) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583265/what-does-s3-methods-mean-in-r)