# Construtor e herança no R

Tags: r

É uma pergunta teórica, mas que talvez possa ajudar a entender um pouco a lógica da programação em `r`.

- O que é e como funciona um **construtor** na linguagem `r`? Qual é a sua utilidade?
- O que é e como funciona a **herança** na linguagem `r`? Como identificar a herança de um objeto e qual é a utilidade de saber a sua herança?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, acho que essa pergunta ficou sem respostas até agora pois esses conceitos são pouco (para não dizer "nada") importantes para se tornar um bom desenvolvedor em R (ao contrário de outras linguagens).

Na minha resposta vou explicar um pouco as principais estruturas e tipos de dados em R e acredito que isso irá ajudá-lo a entender melhor a linguagem.

No R, a estrutura básica de dados é o `vector` (estou usando o nome em inglês para não confundirmos).  Os `vector`s podem ser:

- atômicos - são os vetores normais que conhecemos, com apenas um **tipo**.
- listas - são as listas do R, que podem ser heterogêneas.

Os vetores possuem 3 propriedades importantes:

- Possuem um método `length` - isto é, sempre podemos chamar `length(vetor)`.
- Possuem um tipo, identificado pela função `typeof`. os tipos podem ser `inteiro`, `double`, `character` ou `list` (além dos tipos especiais para funções como `closure` ou `builtin`).
- Podem possuir atributos - use a função `attributes` para obte-los.

A grande maioria dos objetos no R são criados a partir de combinações de `vector`s e seus atributos.

---

**Exemplos**

Uma matriz no R nada mais é do que um vetor atômico com o atributo `dim` preenchido:

```
> x <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
> y <- 1:10
> attr(y, "dim") <- c(5, 2)
> 
> identical(x, y)
[1] TRUE
```

Um `data.frame` é uma lista em que todos os elementos precisam ter o mesmo `length`, o atributo `class` é `data.frame` e possui um atributo `row.names`:

```
> x <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
> y <- list(a = 1:5, b = 1:5)
> attr(y, "class") <- "data.frame"
> attr(y, "row.names") <- 1:5
> 
> identical(x, y)
[1] TRUE
```

Até mesmo o objeto resultado de um `lm` no R é uma lista, com outros atributos preenchidos. Por exemplo, a classe é `lm`:

```
> mod <- lm(mpg ~cyl, data = mtcars)
> typeof(mod)
[1] "list"
> attributes(mod)
$names
 [1] "coefficients"  "residuals"     "effects"       "rank"          "fitted.values" "assign"        "qr"           
 [8] "df.residual"   "xlevels"       "call"          "terms"         "model"        

$class
[1] "lm"
```

---

**Conclusão**

Quase todos os objetos do R são combinações de `vector`s + seus atributos.

---

**Orientação a objeto no R**

No R existem pelo menos 4 maneiras de se criar códigos com orientação a objeto. Para entender melhor a herança entre as classes e etc., vale a pena ler [esse capítulo](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html) do livro *Advanced R*.

Comment: Bem legal a resposta, mas... não respondeu a pergunta original!

Comment: Acredito que pela resposta seja possível entender bem o que é uma classe no R, com isso é possível criá-las e entender heranças sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Só entrando no link externo, não está na resposta de fato! ;-)

Comment: não ficou claro que uma classe é um objeto do R + um atributo classe? e que para identificar o tipo do objeto ou usamos o `typeof`? enfim... está faltando a parte de OO, mas não acho que é o que foi perguntado também. Eu não estou com tempo para escrever muito mais coisa, mas se estiver disposto a completar a resposta ficarei feliz em votar +1 :)

Comment: Eu nunca usei e não conheço nada de R, por isso até achei legal e interessante a sua resposta, porque deu uma pincelada em alguns conceitos da linguagem. Só fiz esse comentário sobre não ter respondido porque as perguntas principais eram: **O que são e como funcionam construtores e herança na linguagem R?**, e você não comentou nada sobre construtores ou herança no R na resposta. Só isso, não me leve a mal. :-)

Comment: ok! não estou levando a mal! estou tentando entender o que você acha que está faltando? se eu tivesse respondido somente como criar uma classe S3 a resposta estaria completa? No R não existe somente uma forma de OO, por isso a minha escolha de explicar como tudo funciona ao invés de escrever uma resposta extensa sobre cada um dos sistemas de OO. talvez não seja a melhor forma de explicar. mas o seu comentário sem nenhum outro adendo é superficial e não ajuda a melhorar em nada a resposta.

Answer (score 5):

O [r](/questions/tagged/r) tem pelo menos 4 sistemas de orientação a objetos (OO): `S3`, `S4`, Reference Classes (também conhecido como `R5` ou `RC`) e `R6`. O último sistema não faz parte do [r-base](/questions/tagged/r-base), mas vem sendo muito utilizado pela comunidade. O `R6` vem de um [pacote](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=R6) com o mesmo nome.

> ## Mas atenção!!! Você deve *mesmo* usar OO no R?

Não se trata aqui de entrar defender este ou aquele paradigma de programação. Ocorre que "R is a functional programming language; embrace it, don’t fight it"<sup>1</sup>.

Ou seja, se você realmente deseja "entender um pouco a lógica da programação em `R`", você deve passar a abordar os problemas de uma forma mais funcional. **Quando o seu problema exigir**, abandone o padrão do [r](/questions/tagged/r) e use a orientação a objetos.

Veja, o sistema `S3` é um sistema de orientação a objetos subordinado a lógica da programação funcional, pois seu objetivo é despachar o objeto corretamente para a função apropriada (método).

## De volta a resposta

Já existe [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32298/orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos-no-r-s3-s4-e-reference-class) sobre a diferença entre os sistemas nativos do [r](/questions/tagged/r). Vou focar a resposta sobre construtor e herança nos sistemas `S3` e `R6` já que são os mais utilizados.

### construtores

#### S3

No `S3` não há uma definição formal da classe. Qualquer objeto pode ser "transformado" na classe desejada.

```
x <- "lala"
class(x) <- "lm"
print(x)
# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Para criar, ou instanciar, uma classe basta adicionar a classe ao objeto, como no exemplo acima, ou adicioná-la por meio da função `structure()`. A boa prática, contudo é criar um construtor para criar objetos daquela classe.

```
pergunta <- function(x) {
  structure(x, class = c("pergunta", class(x)))
}

p1 <- pergunta("Acabei de criar uma classe?")
p1
# [1] "Acabei de criar uma classe?"
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "pergunta"  "character"
```

#### R6

No `R6` você precisa primeiro definir formalmente a classe. É aqui que se define um construtor (item `initialize` em `public`).

```
library(R6)
Pergunta<- R6Class(
  "Pergunta",
  public = list(
    initialize = function(pergunta) {
      self$pergunta <- pergunta
      self$responder()
    },
    pergunta = NULL,
    responder = function() {
      print(sample(c("Sim!", "Não!"), 1))
    }
  )
)
```

Para depois poder instanciá-la (que é quando o construtor é "ativado")

```
set.seed(1)
P1 <- Pergunta$new("Acabei de criar uma classe?")
# [1] "Sim!"
```

Sobre a utilidade dos construtores no `R`: é a mesma do que em qualquer outra linguagem em que se use OO, mas este paradigma tem uso restrito no `R`, como comentado pelo Daniel.

### herança

#### S3

A herança no método `S3` funciona adicionando classes à frente da "classe mãe". Isso ocorre porque a maneira de despachar o objeto para os métodos vai percorrendo o vetor da classe até encontrar um método para aquela função.

```
class(dplyr::starwars)
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Assim, as `tibble`s  podem funcionar tanto para métodos próprios (caso do `print()`), que são preferidos, quanto para métodos do `data.frame` (caso do `summary()`). É por isso também que, mesmo que não tenhamos definido um método para imprimir nossa classe, o `R` se virou. Quando nenhum método é encontrado, o objecto é jogado para o "método default" (`nome_da_funcao.default()`)

#### R6

No caso do `R6`, a função que define a classe tem um argumento para identificar a herança (`inherit`). Atenção para o fato de que deve ser passada própria classe enquanto objeto, e não apenas seu nome.

```
PerguntaRetorica <- R6Class(
  "PerguntaRetorica", 
  inherit = Pergunta,
  public = list(responder = function() print("!?!"))
)
```

Depois que a classe foi definida, podemos instanciá-la.

```
retorica <- PerguntaRetorica$new("Ser ou não ser?")
[1] "!?!"
```

A importância de saber a ascendência de determinado objeto é saber como ele vai se comportar com os métodos. E a forma de fazê-lo é passar o objeto para `class()`.

```
class(retorica)
[1] "PerguntaRetorica" "Pergunta" "R6"
```

Aqui vemos que nossa classe-filha é herdeira de `Pergunta` que por sua vez descende de `R6`

**Referências**

1: [The tidy tools manifesto](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/vignettes/manifesto.html)

2: [Advanced R - Object oriented programming](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html)